# How to unit test map and reduce functions of mongodb Map Reduce query

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, mapreduce

I want to unit test map and reduce functions of Mongodb Map Reduce query through javascript. I explored for it over the web but could not find anything. I got to know about some Javascript testing frameworks(like Jasmine, Mocha). I am new to them. Is it possible to do so using any one of them? Or Has anyone done it?

Comment: Which mongo driver are you using? If you are using Java and want to unit test map-reduce in mongodb with some data, you will need to mock your DAO methods. Unit testing bascically involves not hitting your DB, just ensuring your functionality works by mocking all related entities.

Comment: @vmr I want to unit test map and reduce methods separately, not whole map-reduce query. And I think this should be done by javascript.

Comment: Now I get it, yes you can do it using JavaScript. The question needs to be rephrased to convey the same clearly.Why does MongoDB come into picture here?

Comment: @vmr, I am using mongodb map reduce queries in my application to generate reports, and I want to test whether my map function emits expected values or not.

Comment: @Manish: I just released MockReduce, which mocks the MapReduce in order to achieve testability: https://github.com/djungowski/MockReduce. Hope this helps

Comment: @DominikJungowski Thank You. But I implemented the solution using Jasmine framework.

Answer (score 0):

[MockReduce](https://github.com/djungowski/MockReduce) should have what you need